# What is the correct path when opening a Display with CreateFile?

Tags: c++, winapi

Most minimal example:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ntddvdeo.h>
#include <string>


std::string GetLastErrorAsString()
{
    LPSTR msgBuffer = nullptr;
    DWORD errorMessageID = ::GetLastError();
    std::string msg("No Error");

    if(errorMessageID != 0)
    {
        size_t size = FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
                                     FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
                                     FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                                     NULL,
                                     errorMessageID,
                                     MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, 
                                     SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
                                     (LPSTR)&msgBuffer,
                                     0,
                                     NULL);
        msg = std::string(msgBuffer, size);

        //Free buffer
        LocalFree(msgBuffer);
    }
    return msg;
}

int APIENTRY wWinMain(  _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                        _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                        _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                        _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    DWORD nOutBufferSize = 0;
    DWORD result = NULL;

    typedef struct _DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS {
       UCHAR ucDisplayPolicy;
       UCHAR ucACBrightness;
       UCHAR ucDCBrightness;
    } DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS, *PDISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS;

    DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS displayBrightness;

    displayBrightness.ucDisplayPolicy = 0;
    displayBrightness.ucACBrightness = 50;
    displayBrightness.ucDCBrightness = 0;
    nOutBufferSize = sizeof(displayBrightness);

    HANDLE h = CreateFile(  L"\\\\.\\DISPLAY2",
                            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                            0, NULL,
                            OPEN_EXISTING,
                            0, NULL);

    if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, GetLastErrorAsString().c_str(), "Test", 
                    MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return false;
    }    
    return true;
}
```

I am always getting "Access denied" after `CreateFile`, even when running Visual Studio as Administrator. So the question is, if `\\.\DISPLAY2` is not recognised, what else does Windows accept there, as a device name/path? However, that is the exact device name that I get from `EnumDisplayMonitors`:

```
Found Monitor with 1920x1080 called \\.\DISPLAY1 located at 0:00
Found Monitor with 1680x1050 called \\.\DISPLAY2 located at -1680:240
```

Comment: And what do you expect to be able to do with such a handle?

Comment: @andlabs I want to use it with DeviceIoControl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a handle to physical monitor then get `HMONITOR` from callback of `EnumDisplayMonitors` and use it as an argument for `GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR`.

That will give you the `HANDLE` in `PHYSICAL_MONITOR` object. You can use that handle to for example call [these functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd692964.aspx)

But still, as previously suggested - maybe what you want to get is a handle to device context? Then use [CreateDC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183490.aspx), `CreateFile` won't work here.

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to change the brightness, try the first approach - get physical monitor `HANDLE` and use [SetMonitorBrightness](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd692972.aspx)

**EDIT2:**

Okay, this code works for me and in fact the device path returned from `EnumDisplayMonitors` doesn't work for me either. I'm not an author of this code, I found it [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d940a189-58e8-48e5-a3f0-0ca0f66f1cb1/howto-get-handle-of-a-display-device-from-displaydevicedevicename?forum=vcgeneral) (Couldn't figure it out by myself)

```
DISPLAY_DEVICE ddAdapter;
ddAdapter.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);
for (DWORD dwAdapterNum = 0; EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, dwAdapterNum, &ddAdapter, 0); dwAdapterNum++)
{
    if ((ddAdapter.StateFlags & (DISPLAY_DEVICE_ATTACHED_TO_DESKTOP | DISPLAY_DEVICE_MIRRORING_DRIVER)) == DISPLAY_DEVICE_ATTACHED_TO_DESKTOP)
    {
        DISPLAY_DEVICE ddMonitor;
        ddMonitor.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);
        for (DWORD dwMonitorNum = 0; EnumDisplayDevices(ddAdapter.DeviceName, dwMonitorNum, &ddMonitor, EDD_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_NAME); dwMonitorNum++)
        {
            if (ddMonitor.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_ACTIVE)
            {
                HANDLE hMonitor = CreateFile(ddMonitor.DeviceID, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

                // ...

                CloseHandle(hMonitor);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't need a DC, I want to use it in DeviceIoControl to modify properties of the device. In this case, brightness. I am looking for a way to dim certain devices (Monitors) when conditions are met.

Comment: @Assylum edited with a proposed solution to your problem.

Comment: I tried those functions. GetMonitorCapabilities only returns malformed DDC responses for both monitors I have: http://i.imgur.com/wMnexpS.png Someone told me earlier that it is probably the video driver causing it. However, I am using the latest one available. It is really kind of hard doing this. My last resort would be just using a half transparent black picture as an overlay to dim it.

Comment: Also `GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR` only returns a handle that is always `0x0000000` and the actual product name for my monitor, but not the device path: http://i.imgur.com/QxHvfB1.png

Comment: I am going to accept it when I tried it out tomorrow. I am too tired for today :). But a preliminary thanks is in order :D

Comment: @Assylum: If you hadn't deleted your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42345051/1889329) you could have linked to the helpful comment, instead of trying to piece it together from memory. Deleting a question with helpful user contributions is fairly disrespectful.

Comment: @IInspectable I wish you would stop giving me a hard time for the sake of it. Yesterday, you gave me a hard time for a minor thing like a reinterpret_cast you didn't like, today you are attacking me for getting rid of a thread you said wasn't up to the standards of this site. You are making the experience on this website more frustrating than it has to be and I really wish you would just ignore my posts. You are not helpful, you do not contribute anything of value.

Comment: @Assylum: You seem to be genuinely surprised, that this place is community moderated, and has rules. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to find out, how this site is supposed to work.

Comment: @IInspectable No, I know how this site works and I am not surprised you are acting like this. However, I do not wish to engage with you any further, so leave me alone.

Comment: @Assylum does the code from last edit works for you?